# nao_robot, how to easily make now execute something

Tags: ros, nao-robot, joint-trajectory-action, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello fellows !

I'm a really new ROS user, and have some difficulties interacting with nao.

Before the recent update, I was able to make the robot stand using a MotionCommandBtn rostopic,  but now with this new stack nao_ros, I simply can't find a way to make the robot stand.

Is there a stack that allows us to call directly the behaviours stored on the robot ?
Thanks for the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12291/nao_robot,-how-to-easily-make-now-execute-something/) by [faboul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1515/faboul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The MotionCommandBtn message was dropped in trunk because it only enabled a few hardcoded behaviors. The replacement is the nao_controller node in [nao_driver](http://ros.org/wiki/nao_driver) which enables arbitrary joint trajectories and pose_manager in [nao_remote](http://ros.org/wiki/nao_remote) which enables the robot to assume fixed body poses via an actionlib interface. All this is fully configurable and a few default poses are loaded from the parameter server: "crouch" (sit down), "zero", "init" (stand up).

Your robot can enter these poses if nao_controller and nao_remote are running (there are configured launchfiles in their packages), and you call the corresponding action just like the Gamepad teleoperation does on button presses. The new actionlib interface has the advantage that you can now be sure that the action was called properly and finished completely.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3